# my line of code is not executing in delay - android

Tags: android, multithreading, imagebutton, android-image

The strangest thing is happening. In my onClick(View ...) I have blocks of code, mostly 'if/else' blocks. The sequence is (in pseudo-code, to save you lengthy code):

1. I have an image that needs setting using imageButton.setImageResource(randomImage); then
2. I have a MediaPlayer associated with this image that needs playing, then
3. I place a sleep(1800) here otherwise the MediaPlayer runs into the next MediaPlayer (this works fine)
4. This image is compare to another image. If its not the same, then another MediaPlayer named 'boo' is played, and the image that should have been displayed in code 1. above, is replaced by 'flag' image.  else //if its the right image then
5. Switch to 'another' image, play it's corresponding MeidaPlayer, Play a 'cheers' MediaPlayer and change image to a 'tick' image, then do some other logic stuff.

But what is happening is that the code 2. is playing, code 3. is happening. code 4. only the 'boo' mediaplayer is happening and I notice the imagebutton flashing. The image that was supposed to be set in code 1. is delayed and is happening only AFTER the 'boo' mediaplayer. The 'flag' image that replaces the first image setting in code 1. is happening but because code 1. is in delay, what is happening is that the image is not changing (although it is, it's just in delay and then it flashes so quickly that it appears not to change). So code 1. is in delay. 
Also, if it goes into the else and the right image is clicked, then the image in code 5. DOES switch to 'another', but the corresponding MeidaPlayer doesn't play, the 'cheers' MediaPlayer doesn't play, the 'tick' image doesn't display, and the other logic doesn't occur. Its as if it is ignoring the code. 
What's happening here? Is this a multi-threading situation here? Grouping different parts of the code in their own threads and starting them at once only throws exceptions. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think using an alarm manager to wake your program up is more likely to give you timings closer to what you specified than using sleep() on Android.  But I don't know why sleep() doesn't really behave.

Comment: 'I place a sleep(1800) here' OK, lets start with that.  Get rid of it.  Restructure your code so that this sleep() call in the GUI thread is not needed.  Do not sleep or wait in GUI event handlers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delay your code, use `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)`. This won't block the UI thread, and will execute when you want it to.

Whitout your code, it's really unclear what are you trying to achive, and how are you trying to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found a way round it that did not need to use sleep() at all. I just moved a boolean parameter a bit further up the code and it worked magically. So no need to play with the thread. Thanks everyone and good tip about the Handler.postDe.....will use for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain Adam's idea.

Put this in your Activity class :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
Runnable _rnbl = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        // Your code
    }   
};
```

And call it like this

```
handler.postDelayed(_rnbl , 5000);
```